# Font-style CSS not applying to HTML element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working through exercises in the Beginning Javascript Book. I'm stuck on an exercise where I use the DOM to add a class to an element to change the style of the text. When I open this page in Chrome the div element is underlined but not italic. What's wrong with my code?

```
<head>
    <title>Chapter 9, Example 5</title>
    <style>
        #divAdvert {
            font: 12pt Verdana;
        }

        .new-style {
            font-style: italic;
            text-decoration: underline;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="divAdvert">
        Here is an advertisement.
    </div>

    <script>
        var divAdvert = document.getElementById("divAdvert");
        divAdvert.className = "new-style";
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `font` in CSS, that is a short cut property for several things including `font-style`. The default there is `normal` and that's why it's not set. Your `.new-style` is overridden by that because ID has a higher specificity than class.

The one way around it is to set your font properties specifically.

```
#divAdvert {
        font-size: 12px; 
        font-family: Verdana;
    }
```

In addition, you should know that `pt` is for print and should not be used for the web.

Comment: That's not the *only way around*, you can also give the selector more importance, or even abuse the `!important` keyword, while this latter is really not recommended.

Answer (score 4):

Try making the style more specific so the font style isn't given precedence in the id selector

```
 <style>
#divAdvert {
    font-size: 12pt;
    font-family: Verdana;
}

.new-style {
    font-style: italic;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
</style>
```

@Kaiido made a good point in the comment about explaining why this works.

When you use the short hand "font" style you are actually setting multiple styles such as font-size and font-family as you show in your example. But it also can be used to set other font properties like font-weight, font-style etc.  If you don't pass a value in that short hand style rule it gets the default values. The reason your class wasn't overriding it was because your id selector was setting the font-style to the default value and your class selector was setting it to italic. However, the id selector has a higher specificity than the class selector so its rules take precedence. Changing the id selector to not set the font-style (through the default value applied when you used the short hand "font" rule) allows the class to apply the font-style rule. Another solution as @Kaiido mentioned would be to just make the class selector have a higher specificity than the id selector which could be done like this:

```
    #divAdvert {
        font: 12pt Verdana;
    }

    #divAdvert.new-style {
        font-style: italic;
        text-decoration: underline;
    }
```

Because you have now made the selector with the class more specific than the id selector alone, its rules will override the original id selector.

Comment: An explanation on the underlying reasons it would fix the issue would probably be benificial to this answer. (i.e explain how shorthands works) Ps: an alternative could also be to be more specific in the selector (`#divAdvert.new-style`)

Answer (score 0):

Put important in font-style

```
#divAdvert {
        font: 12pt Verdana;
    }

    .new-style {
        font-style: italic !important;
        text-decoration: underline;
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/z402o3bL/

Comment: Don't get in the habit of using !important. It's better to get an understanding of how CSS specificity works.

Comment: Accepted. That was just a solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
.new-style {
    font-style:italic !important;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
```

It's not the best practice but it works. The !important use it only when you need to override styles.